# Area 51 should have its own privileges pages

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, area-51, privileges

On all main Stack Exchange sites, clicking on your reputation score at the top of the screen directs you to [the privileges page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges). On Area 51, however, that is not the case. In fact, the page [does not even exist](http://area51.stackexchange.com/privileges). Instead, you have to check the FAQ to find the information you're looking for.

I think Area 51 should function like every other site on the network and have its own privileges pages. It'd be more intuitive and easy to find than it currently is.

Comment: yes, why not? +1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Area 51 now has its own [privileges pages](http://area51.stackexchange.com/privileges).

Answer (score 0):

Since the privledge list is so small on the [Area 51 FAQ](http://area51.stackexchange.com/faq).  I can understand why it might not need its own page.

However I agree that the user experience would be more consistent and easier to follow if it lined up closer with other sites.

Comment: Borror0 already pointed out that the privileges are in the FAQ.

Comment: @ChrisF, yea not sure how I missed that.  I will update my answer.